# What licence is required for a service to call MS CRM via the web services?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

What licence is required for an external service to call MS CRM via the web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is for your external program to authenticate with the web services using the credentials of a user with a Full/Professional license.  A limited license does give some expanded permissions through the API but they are still fairly limited.

More details about the license types:
http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2013/04/11/full-vs-limited-licenses-in-dynamics-crm-2011/

Comment: Thanks for the response ... what is a "full licence"?  According to a blog post by the CRM team, there is Essential / Basic / Professional plus Administrative and Non-Interactive  ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2013/10/30/license-types-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-and-microsoft-dynamics-crm-online.aspx

Comment: In the new terminology you should be connecting using a Professional license.  You can connect using an Essential or Basic license but you will be limited to operations that those license types support.  For example if your program connects to the services using a Basic license it will only be able to access the basic functionality described in that article.